# Adding Firebase to Flask Server

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to add Firebase to my flask server(first time so I'm learning). But am getting this error when I try to run main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
│  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>

│    from .forms import FirePut
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Line 7 corresponds with this

```
from .forms import FirePut
```

I have tried using python -m main.py to compile.
Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an `__init__.py` at every level of the project? [This article](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/) would also be informative.